# Java: defineClass and inner classes

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

In my own classloader I get all entries from jar file and use defineClass() to load classes to memory.

My problem is that if jar has inner classes (e.g. MyClass$1.class) the defineClass method fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName` exception.

Obviously java needs all files from jar to make it work but how the inner classes can be loaded?

Comment: Do we get the more of the exception trace?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a normal `URLClassLoader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyClass$1.class should match an anonymous inner class. If your inner class is named, it should be MyClass$InnerClass.class